# unbound row in datagridview in c#

Tags: c#

I have

```
Class A
{
private string mName;
private int mId;
private int mType;
private int mqty;
/*
property to view variables.
*/
}

BindingList<A> listofA =  new BindingList<A>();
```

"listofA" is bound to to datagridview control.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource=listofA;
```

which is displayed as.

```
------------------
|Name|Id|Type|Qty|
------------------
|CatA| 1|   0|  5|
|CatB| 2|   0|  6|
|DogA| 3|   1|  7|
|DogB| 4|   1|  8|
```

I want an unbound row to display.

```
------------------
|Name|Id|Type|Qty|
------------------
|CatA| 1|   0|  5|
|CatB| 2|   0|  6|
|Cats|__|   0| 11| <------sum of qty 
|DogA| 3|   1|  7|
|DogB| 4|   1|  8| 
|Dogs|__|   1| 15| <------sum of qty
```

I was thinking of adding a Bool in "class A" and it would act as an item if false and as sum if true.

Is there a better way to do this.

Comment: You probably do this in your real code, but make sure `listofA` is sorted. Don't rely on your DAL to give it to you sorted the way you need it to do this.

Comment: You won't even need that extra bool field, only you need to add those rows(i.e. containing the Sum value) in datatable by which you are binding the grid.

Comment: The extra field could be used to ensure the totals are always the last row of a given category, no? ...or the id..

Comment: Yes the extra field is at the end of a given category/type

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is code in the RowDataBound event :

1) compare data from previous row (ex:animal type). If different then you know you've reached the end of a category, if the same, you should sum-up the different values you need to sum up

2a) type was the same, you did the sumup, there's nothing more to do

2b) type was different, you create a new row with the sum-up values and reset the sum variables

Comment: RowDataBound is not an event of datagridview.

Comment: My bad, I read GridView and didn't realize we were talking winforms and not ASP.NET . Then maybe you could make use of the [`RowPrePaint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.onrowprepaint.aspx) event ? I hope I'm not telling something stupid, I'm not into winforms myself...